# Can an employer terminate a contract immediately if I disclose I am joining a competitor at a future date?

Tags: job-offer, united-states, termination, california

I have a job offer from my employer's competitor. I am not bound by any non-compete clauses. Colleagues often plan their departures to occur right after equity vesting dates and then pre-announce this with their managers a few weeks before. If I disclosed my intention today to join the competitor after the next equity vesting date, would my employer be able to terminate my contract immediately, denying me the vesting equity, without any other cause? Is this likely? The relevant space is tech companies in California.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: but when is the vesting date?  is it once a year ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

California is at will. They can fire you instantly. However they tend not to do that-  it makes people in the company upset. Its more normal that you give 2 weeks notice, and then they decide to just pay you to sit those 2 weeks if you're leaving to a competitor.  But they're not forced to do that, just like you're not forced to give 2 weeks notice.  It's just etiquette.

If you're really worried about the vesting date, I wouldn't hand in my notice until the shares are vested.  That's the safest path.  Try to push the start date at the new company to 2 weeks after vesting date, or give less than 2 weeks notice and accept you'll piss people off at the old job.

Comment: A lot of employees in CA have employment contracts which overrule at-will. A lot of these contracts have mandated notice periods.

Comment: Great context. I am partially tempted to disclose that I'm going to a competitor in the hope that that might generate a better counter-offer from my current employer, but it seems risky for the reasons you mention. I would feel relatively safe giving notice before the vesting date but not revealing my destination, and I don't see any obvious ethical issues with that.

Comment: @zvy68625 A counteroffer is possible, but I wouldn't try that unless you were willing to go through with it.  Its a bad way to bluff.  You're better off with that from a non-competitor.  That way its not a walk off situation (if you were going to a non-competitor they don't generally walk you out, they let you work your notice.  For example if you work for Facebook and go to Oracle, they wouldn't walk you out).

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I'd be curious about that.  I've never seen one.  And what do they do if you just refuse to show up?  Slavery is illegal.

Comment: Only about 75% of employed Americans are at-will. If they refuse to show up, they can be sued for breach of contract. For instance, if you breach the notice period, they may be able to sue for damages caused by you suddenly deciding not to work.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I'd love to see some backup on that.  There's only 1 state that isn't at will, and I've never heard of anyone having a contractual notice period.  Ever.  I have doubts on whether such a clause would hold up in court, except maybe for a top executive.

Comment: I especially doubt it because if a clause like that was generally legal, it would be used in pretty much 100% of cases, if for no other reason for jerk bosses to screw people over.

Comment: "At-Will" is the default condition in most states. However, because America is the land of the free, employers and employees are able to negotiate contracts that overrule "at-will". For CA, you can look here for more information: https://www.rhdtlaw.com/employee-contracts-in-california/

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I'd still like you to show some backup of your claim 25% of America isn't at will.  Because I have never met a non at-will employee, or seen a contract that specifies a notice period.  I also doubt for a non-executive that any court would find a penny in damages beyond not paying them for the notice not worked.  But the correct move if you are in that situation is to go in and do nothing, and force them to fire you or pay you for surfing the web.

Comment: I got the figure from: https://www.betterteam.com/at-will-employment. I have no reason to doubt that figure, and really, no willingness to verify it either.

Comment: @GabeSechan: _"if a clause like that was generally legal, it would be used in pretty much 100% of cases, if for no other reason for jerk bosses to screw people over"_ Notice periods can cut both ways and are more often in favor of the employee. Coming from a culture with significant worker protection compared to the US, the jerk bosses here predominantly argue for _not_ wanting/needing notice periods, specifically pointing at the US system, because jerk bosses like the ability to fire someone with immediate effect, rather than allowing the employee time to find a new stable source of income.

Comment: @GabeSechan: _"I also doubt for a non-executive that any court would find a penny in damages beyond not paying them for the notice not worked."_ Are you saying that in your definition, a non-executive employee would not generate more value to the company than the company pays in wages to that employee? If so, then you don't understand the basic economics at play here. But otherwise, then you must agree that having an unscheduled absent employee can lose the company more revenue than it gains by not paying the employee's wage, which negates your "not a penny in damages" thought.

Comment: @zvy68625 Expecting a counter-offer, when putting the bosses "under the knife" is risky. One of my bosses used to say, that if the employee didn't come discuss sooner about a raise, then there is no trust, and he will let them leave.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie With no disrespect meant to you-  I spent over an hour googling for every combination of 75%, 25%, at will and notice period I could think of and couldn't find any support for it.   I don't think you're pulling it from your ass, but I think they are.

Comment: @Flater "Could have generated income" isn't damages.  Damages require actual loss. That's why if I destroy something you own, you get the value its worth in the condition it is when I destroyed it, not what it would be worth if you fixed it up and sold it at the top of the market.  Even if you had all the materials ready to fix it and were going to do it that afternoon.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Actually after reading that page more-  there's a difference between not being at will and having a notice period.  They list a bunch of exceptions to at will employment that would not enforce a notice period.  That's probably the VAST majority of what they claim is the 26%.

Comment: @GabeSechan You two are arguing apples and oranges.  25% of the US workforce is definitely not at-will.  Just look up the stats for 'public sector' and 'private sector union' percentages (15%, 6%) and you'll find you're already at 21% of the workforce being not at-will.  That said, it's definitely not true that 25% of the private sector, non-unionized employees are not-at-will, which is probably what you're visualizing in your head.

Comment: @GabeSechan: Absence can be tactically played to cause damage, rather than a lack of new revenue. There is a huge difference in intent on the employee's and employer's parts here, and any agreement has to account for the possibility of someone causing a tactical absence with specific intent to spite the other party. This could be an employer spitefully putting the employee without an income at a difficult time, or the employee spitefully being absent and causing a significant problem for the company (e.g. if a coordinated/planned task with multiple people cannot commence without the absentee).

Comment: @GabeSechan - it is interesting that you do know that announcing that you join competitor pretty much guarantees that employment will be terminated immediately and you'll be walked out but yet answer says exact opposite "However they tend not to do that"...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov They tend not to terminate you.  They tend to pay you to not work for 2 weeks instead.  Basically because not honoring a notice period incentivizes others not to give one in the future.  The difference being you're paid for the 2 weeks you would have worked, which is all you generally care about.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it will not. except you have a reference case. Because generally speaking, if the company terminate your contract, they have to pay. Who would prefer to pay you when you decide to go??

If you really worry about it, then make sure your manager or HR don't know where you leave your current company. You could choose not mention where you go, or you could lie.

If you can not make sure your manager or HR know where you go before the last day you leave your current company, then wait for they know it. The less time they have, more stable your offer it is, and the less chance they would fire you.